# How do I copy ArrayList<T> in java multi-threaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In thread A, an `ArrayList` is created. It is managed from thread A only.
In thread B, I want to copy that to a new instance.

The requirement is that `copyList` should not fail and should return a consistent version of the list (= existed at some time at least during the  copying process).

My approach is this:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> copyList(ArrayList<? extends T> list) {
    List<? extends T> unmodifiableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    return new ArrayList<T>(unmodifiableList);
}
```

Q1: Does that satisfy the requirements?

Q2: How can I do the same without `Collections.unmodifiableList` with proably iterators and try-catch blocks?

**UPD. That is an interview question I was asked a year ago. I understand this a bad idea to use non-thread-safe collections like ArrayList in multithreaded environment**

Comment: The ArrayList used by A can be modified by A or simply read?

Comment: Another question which Thread calls copyList ?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto that's thread B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *absolutely* no way to create a copy of a *plain* ArrayList *if* the "owning" thread does not offer some protocol to do so.

Without any protocol, thread A can modify the list potentially at *any time*, meaning thread B *never* gets a chance to ensure that is sees a consistent state of the list.

To actually allow a consistent copy to be made, thread A *must* ensure that any modifications it has made are written to memory and are visible to other threads.

Normally, the VM is allowed to reorder instructions, reads and writes as it sees fit, provided no difference can be observed from within the thread executing the program. This includes, for example, delaying writes by holding values in CPU registers or on the local stack.

The only way to ensure that everything is consistently written to main menory, is for thread A to execute an instruction that presents a reordering barrier to the VM (e.g. synchronized block or volatile field access).

So without some cooperation from thread A, there is no way to ensure above conditions are guaranteed to be fulfilled.

Common methods of circumventing this are to synchronize access to the List by only using it in a safely wrapped form (Collections.synchronizedCollection), or use of a List implementation that has these guarantees built in (any type of concurrent list implementation).

Answer (score 7):

No. `ArrayList` is not thread safe and you are not using an explicit `synchronization`.

While you are executing the method unmodifiableList the first thread can modify the original list and you will have a not valid unmodifiable list.

The simplest way I think is the following:

- Replace the List with a synchronized version of it.
- On the copy list synchronize on the arrayList and make a copy

For example, something like:

```
List<T> l = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<T>());

...

public static <T> List<T> copyList(List<? extends T> list) {
    List<T> copyList = null;
    synchronized(list) {
        copyList = new ArrayList<T>(list);
    }
    return copyList;
}
```

Comment: @JornVernee many thanks. I edited the answer two times and I changed leaving partially the old answer. Thanks again

Comment: this can only work if the provided list in copyList is the synchronizedList list and not an ArrayList otherwise the mutex used while modifying the list won't be the same as the one user while copying it which would make the code invalid

Comment: @NicolasFilotto you are right. As I said to Jorn. There were many typos because the inital answer was different and changing it I lost something. Thanks.

Comment: and you don't need the varilable copyList at all, simply call return new ArrayList<T>(list); in your synchronized block

Answer (score 4):

You should synchronize access to the `ArrayList`, or replace `ArrayList` with a concurrent collection like [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).
Without doing that you might end up with a copy that is inconsistent.

Comment: So, if use `new CopyOnWriteArrayList(list)` and during this costly call someone modifies the collection, will I get an exception or an inconsistent copy?

Comment: @IlyaSmagin Wait, you should use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` from the start, so no `ArrayList` at all in thread A. `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is a replacement for the `ArrayList` if you want to use multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for `Collections.unmodifiableList(...)` says, "Returns an unmodifiable *view* of the specified list."

The key word there is "view".  That means it does *not* copy the data.  All it does is create a wrapper for the given list with mutators that all throw exceptions rather than modify the base list.

---

> Yes, but I acually create new ArrayList(Collections.unmodif...), wouldn't this work?

Oops!  I missed that.  If you're going to copy the list, then there's no point in calling `unmodifiableList()`.  The only code that will ever access the unmodifiable view is the code that's right there in the same method where it's created.  You don't have to worry about that code modifying the list contents because *you* wrote it.

On the other hand, if you're going to copy the list when other threads could be updating the list, then you're going to need `synchronized` all around.  Every place where code could update the list needs to be in a `synchronized` block, as does the code that makes the copy.  Of course, all of those synchronized blocks must synchronize on the same object.

Some programmers will use the list object itself as the lock object.  Others will prefer to use a separate object.

Comment: Yes, but I acually create new ArrayList(Collections.unmodif...), wouldn't this work?

Answer (score 1):

> Q1: Does that satisfy the requirements?

If the provided list is modified while copying it using `new ArrayList<T>(unmodifiableList)`, you will get a `ConcurrentModificationException` even if you wrapped it using `Collections.unmodifiableList` because the `Iterator` of an `UnmodifiableList` simply calls the `Iterator` of the wrapped list and here as it is a non thread safe list you can still get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

What you could do is indeed use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead as it is a thread safe list implementation that provides consistent snapshots of the `List` when you try to iterate over it. Another way could be to make the Thread A push for other threads regularly a safe copy of it using `new ArrayList<T>(myList)` as it is the only thread that modifies it we know that while creating the copy no other thread will modify it so it would be safe.

> Q2: How can I do the same without `Collections.unmodifiableList` with
>   probably iterators and try-catch blocks?

As mentioned above `Collections.unmodifiableList` is not helping here to make it thread safe, for me the only thing that could make sense is actually the opposite: the thread A (the only thread that can modify the list) creates a safe copy of your `ArrayList` using `new ArrayList<T>(list)` then it pushes to other threads an unmodified list of it using `Collections.unmodifiableList(list)`.

Generally speaking you should avoid specifying implementations in your method's definition especially public ones, you should only use interfaces or abstract classes because otherwise you would provide an implementation details to the users of your API which is not expected. So here it should be `List` or `Collection` not `ArrayList`.